# Lombok + QueryDsl + Mapstruct: error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Entity: javax.persistence.Entity

Tags: java, spring, lombok, querydsl, mapstruct

Here is the error during maven compile

**error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Entity: javax.persistence.Entity**

I deleted all entity classes and compile was ok.

Is it a bug in annotation processor?

I tried different combinations for annotation processors order.

And here is my full pom xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.x</groupId>
    <artifactId>xx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>xx</name>
    <description>CRUD API and logic for xx</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
        <base-service-with-all-entities.version>1.0.74-SNAPSHOT</base-service-with-all-entities.version>
        <base-test-service.version>0.0.9-SNAPSHOT</base-test-service.version>
        <feign.version>11.6</feign.version>
        <eureka-client.version>1.10.16</eureka-client.version>
        <spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon.version>2.2.9.RELEASE</spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon.version>

        <querydsl.version>5.0.0</querydsl.version>
        <postgresql.version>42.2.23.jre7</postgresql.version>
        <liquibase-core.version>4.4.1</liquibase-core.version>

        <nv-i18n.version>1.28</nv-i18n.version>
        <springfox.version>3.0.0</springfox.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.0.Beta1</mapstruct.version>
        <commons-codec.version>1.15</commons-codec.version>

        <docker.image.name>xxx/${artifactId}</docker.image.name>
        <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
        <docker.artifact.version>${git.branch}_${git.commit.time}-${git.commit.id.abbrev}</docker.artifact.version>
        <docker.image.tag>${docker.artifact.version}</docker.image.tag>

        <testcontainers.version>1.15.3</testcontainers.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.20</lombok.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2020.0.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>https://nexus.y.com/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>https://nexus.y.com/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>https://nexus.y.com/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>https://nexus.y.com/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.x</groupId>
            <artifactId>base-service-with-all-entities</artifactId>
            <version>${base-service-with-all-entities.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.x</groupId>
            <artifactId>base-test-service</artifactId>
            <version>${base-test-service.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>${feign.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-gson</artifactId>
            <version>${feign.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${feign.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-codec.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
            <artifactId>nv-i18n</artifactId>
            <version>${nv-i18n.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${parent.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <jvmArguments>--enable-preview</jvmArguments>
                    <mainClass>io.x.xx.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.13</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.image.name}</repository>
                    <tag>${docker.image.tag}</tag>
                    <contextDirectory>target/dockerbuild</contextDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <compilerArg>--enable-preview</compilerArg>
                        <compilerArg>-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring</compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                        <annotationProcessor>lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor
                        </annotationProcessor>
                        <annotationProcessor>org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>get-the-git-info</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <offline>true</offline>
                    <useNativeGit>true</useNativeGit>
                    <dateFormat>yyyyMMdd</dateFormat>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFilename>target/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                    <commitIdGenerationMode>full</commitIdGenerationMode>
                    <injectAllReactorProjects>true</injectAllReactorProjects>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/dockerbuild</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                                    <include>Dockerfile</include>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                                    <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Build-Version>${docker.image.tag}</Build-Version>
                            <Build-Revision>${docker.image.tag}</Build-Revision>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the version 5.0.0 and just add classifier 'jakarta' to jpa or/and apt querydsl dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
  <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

QueryDsl does not declare a dependency to the JPA API. Maybe this is a bug. To fix this issue add the dependency manually as a `path` element to the `annotationProcessorPaths`. The annotation processor dependencies and the Maven dependencies are distinct, hence adding it as a dependency or plugin dependency does not work.

The example is processing it in a separate phase. You can also include it in the default Maven compiler plugin configuration.

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>querydsl</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <proc>only</proc>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <path>
                                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                                    <classifier>jpa</classifier>
                                    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                                </path>
                                <!-- querydsl is not declaring a dependency to JPA-->
                                <path>
                                    <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>2.2.3</version>
                                </path>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have a dependency to JPA declared. QueryDSL expects the API to be provided by the application. You can fix this by declaring a dependency to the JPA API:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Although usually `javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api` will be provided transitively through your JPA implentation (i.e. your dependency on `hibernate-core`).

Comment: This only for spring 5. On `Spring 6` `javax.persistence-api` is replaced by `jakarta.persistence-api`